# No importa si agrego onclick a muchos objetos?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo algo y necesito saber si es bueno, osea si está okay si pongo onclick a muchos objetos, lo que pasa es que quiero que al clickear en un objeto, se abra una ventana con la info de ese objeto que clikeé, osea, los objetos vienen de una api entonces lo que hice fue agregar el onclick al padre de los objetos, pero para lo que necesito no me gustaría hacer eso, alguna sugerencia?

De esto...

```
Padre (Con el evento onclick, recibe quien fue clikeado y luego hace algo)

Hijo
Hijo
Hijo
```

A esto...

```
Padre

Hijo (Cuando se clickea, hace algo)
Hijo (Cuando se clickea, hace algo)
Hijo (Cuando se clickea, hace algo)
```

Espero me haya podido expresar de buena manera.

Comment: Hola Diego, ¿podrías colocar el código? Es para tener el contexto de la pregunta.

Comment: no hay ningun problema que varios elementos tengan un onclick para abrir su info... el problema seria que hagas una info estática para cada uno de los elementos... la mejor idea seria hacer una plantilla para todos y según el elemento que haya dado click los valores cambien dinamicamente la info

Comment: Puedes hacerlo, no pasa nada, aun que lo ideal es como lo comenta David y crear una funcion para reducir las lineas de código. Si estas usando react usa handleClick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Agregar `onclick` a objetos

Puedes hacerlo, pero una forma más elegante es ésta:

Código JavaScript:

```js
let hijos = document.querySelectorAll("#padre .hijo");

for( let elemento of hijos )
  elemento.onclick = () => {
    // Tus instrucciones
  }
```

Código HTML:

```html
<div id="padre">
  <div class="hijo">1</div>
  <div class="hijo">2</div>
  <div class="hijo">3</div>
  <div class="hijo">4</div>
</div>
```

**Importante:** esta respuesta no se debe tomar como solución definitiva al problema planteado. El objetivo es orientar sobre una posible forma de solucionarlo.

Comment: Correcto, había pensado algo parecido pero la cosa es, ¿acaso no es lo mismo?

Comment: Si, pero con la diferencia de que tendrías un código HTML más limpio.

Comment: Y en cuestión de recursos? eso afecto o no es notable?

Comment: No he medido la diferencia de aplicar `<div class="hijo" onclick="unaFuncion(this)"></div>` sobre `elemento.onclick = () => { /* Instrucciones*/ }` en cuanto a consumo de recursos de hardware (excepto en el almacenamiento). Lo que si es seguro es que la segunda es más fácil de mantener que la primera. A pequeña escala es inapreciable, pero a mayor escala el impacto es significativo.

Comment: Ahh vale, perfecto, me conformo con que de momento no hay mucho problema con ello, muchas gracias bro <3

Comment: Dale Diego. Para eso estamos.